# Is there a semantically better way to create this layout of text in circles?

Tags: html, css

I've come up with what seems like a very hacky, non-semantic way to code a design that I'd like to use. Basically, it's a set of 4 equal-sized circles, distributed so their centers are the same as those of equilateral triangles. I've used a bunch of presentational divs to solve two issues: (1) to get the spacing of the circles right, I need their bounding boxes to overlap; and (2) to vertically space text in the circles without changing their size, it seems like I need to use display:table in my CSS.

It works, but I hate it, and I feel like there has to be a better way. I am new to CSS, and this method is the result of a fair amount of research about how to solve this design problem.

The design is at this codepen: http://codepen.io/bhagerty/pen/rejEPZ

(I put borders on a bunch of the elements just to show the structure.)

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
  <h1 id="home_title">test</h1>
<div id="container_1">

    <div id="picture" class="box">
      <div class="circle_outer">
        <div class="circle_inner">
          <div class="inner-text">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/%22In_Which_We_Serve%22_Advertisement_1943.jpg/1024px-%22In_Which_We_Serve%22_Advertisement_1943.jpg" width=100%; />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="dog" class="box">
      <div class="circle_outer">
        <div class="circle_inner">
          <div class="inner-text">
            dog
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="shoes" class="box">
      <div class="circle_outer">
        <div class="circle_inner">
          <div class="inner-text">
            shoes
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="dance" class="box">
      <div class="circle_outer">
        <div class="circle_inner">
          <div class="inner-text">
            dance
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer_1">
      Footer<br>
      test
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1#home_title {
  text-align: center; 
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .1rem 0 .5rem 0;;
  background-color: grey;
}
div#container_1 {
  border: green solid 5px;
  width: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

div.box {
  border: red solid 1px; 
  position: absolute;
  width: 53.6%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
}

/*pseudo-element to give relative height,
per http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/PFPDU/
and http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html */

div.box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

/* if inner text has position relative, it influences the size of the containing box */
/*setting all of the positions to zero forces it inside the circle for some reason */

.circle_outer {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: black solid 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* to create breathing room all around, set top and left to 1/2 of 100% - width (where width = height) */
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.circle_inner {
/*  border: grey solid 5px; */
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner-text {
  display: table-cell;
/*  border: green solid 2px; */
  font-size: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/*First bounding box is at upper left corner */
div#picture {
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

/*Percent positions all based on W, derived from fact
that bounding boxes circumscribe tangent circles, and 
circle centers are connected by equilateral triangles */

div#dog {
  left: 46.4%;
  margin-top: 26.8%;
}
div#shoes {
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 53.6%;
}

div#dance {
  left: 46.4%;
  margin-top: 80.4%;
}

div#footer_1 {
  border: red solid 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 137%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

I much appreciate any thoughts or help. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using **html5** simply use a **canvas** element, with javascript; I will post an example on codepen shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, IMO what you've done is really good. I wouldn't be too concerned about the extra divs.

But, it can be done with fewer divs, making use of float and margins.

[Codepen is here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKWQgX)

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1#home_title {
  text-align: center; 
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .1rem 0 .5rem 0;;
  background-color: grey;
}
div#container_1 {
  border: green solid 5px;
  width: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.box {
  border: red solid 1px; 
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  width: 53.6%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin-bottom:-27%;
}
div.box:nth-child(2n) {
  float:right;
}
div.box:nth-child(2n+1) {
  float:left;
}

/*pseudo-element to give relative height,
per http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/PFPDU/
and http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html */

div.box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

/* if inner text has position relative, it influences the size of the containing box */
/*setting all of the positions to zero forces it inside the circle for some reason */

.featuring {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: black solid 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* to create breathing room all around, set top and left to 1/2 of 100% - width (where width = height) */
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.featuring:before {
  content:'';
  margin-left:-0.25em;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:100%;
}

/*Percent positions all based on W, derived from fact
that bounding boxes circumscribe tangent circles, and 
circle centers are connected by equilateral triangles */

div#footer_1 {
  border: red solid 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 137%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="home_title">test</h1>
<div id="container_1">
   
    <div id="picture" class="box">
        <div class="featuring">
             <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/%22In_Which_We_Serve%22_Advertisement_1943.jpg/1024px-%22In_Which_We_Serve%22_Advertisement_1943.jpg" width=100%; />
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="dog" class="box">
      <div class="featuring">
            dog
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="shoes" class="box">
      <div class="featuring">
            shoes
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="dance" class="box">
      <div class="featuring">
            dance
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="footer_1">
      Footer<br>
      test
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I tried using floats, but I found that I couldn't get things to overlap when I did so. I obviously was doing something wrong. I will take a closer look at your code to pick up the tricks I was missing.